# Multiple Training Set LSTM RNN

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am attempting to train an LSTM RRN however I am running into the issue that I have multiple sets of sequential data. Is there a way to prepare the data, rather than sending it all in together, so as to train the model properly or do I have to accept that there will be some faulty overlap between the sets.

Comment: Can you provide examples of what you are trying to achieve? It's unclear.

Comment: Yeah sorry, it also might be a bad question since I'm new. So I'm training a RNN on songs but if I feed them into the model in one long sequence there will be small error in the training since the end of one song will not influence the start of the next song